# WATIR. Can you use Begin > Rescue within a function / method?

Tags: ruby, function, watir, rescue

I'm trying to have a function that handles exceptions for different elements in the system. The Begin / Rescue code works, but once it's placed within a function, the Rescue part doesn't work and the exceptions don't get caught.

This is the exception code that works:

```
//..begin
    browser.select_list(:id => "P5500_P_NATIONALITY").select("Americans")
    rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError, Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException
    print "Error handling caught an exception: Relationships Page. See log."
    print "\n"
    log_fileWriter("after_header","Relationship Page:",$exception_error_code,"2",test_id)
    screenCapture(browser,"Add Relationship",test_id)

end//..
```

This is the same code but now in a function. this doesn't work.

```
//..def exception_check(element_to_check) 
    begin
         element_to_check
         rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError, Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException
         print "Error handling caught an exception: Relationships Page. See log."
         print "\n"
         log_fileWriter("after_header","Relationship Page:",$exception_error_code,"2",test_id)
         screenCapture(browser,"Add Relationship",test_id)

    end
end

exception_check(browser.select_list(:id => "P5500_P_NATIONALITY").select("Americans")) //..
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Basically the objective is to have as many exception traps as possible without needing multiple Begin/Rescue blocks.

Thanks Justin for looking. It still doesn't reach the rescue block within the function. My updated code looks like this as per your suggestion:

```
//..
def exception_check
    yield
    rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError, Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException
    print "Error handling caught an exception: Relationships Page. See log."
    print "\n"
    log_fileWriter("after_header","Relationship Page:",$exception_error_code,"2",test_id)
    screenCapture(browser,"Add Relationship",test_id)
end

exception_check { browser.select_list(:id => "P5500_P_NATIONALITY").select("Americans") }
//..
```

This is the same code applied for google.ca with the field name deliberately set wrong to bring out the exception:

//..

```
test_env = "https://www.google.ca/"
browser = Watir::Browser.new # Defaults to use Chrome
browser.goto(test_env)


def exception_check
    yield
    rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError, Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException
    print "Error handling caught an exception: Relationships Page. See log."
    print "\n"
    log_fileWriter("after_header","Relationship Page:",$exception_error_code,"2",test_id)
    screenCapture(browser,"Add Relationship",test_id)
end


exception_check { browser.text_field(:name => "qq").set("watir") }
```

//..

And here is the exception that gets thrown:
//..

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:813:in `rescue in element_call': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:name=>"qq", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:805:in `element_call'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/user_editable.rb:10:in `set'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:26:in `block in <main>'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:16:in `exception_check'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:26:in `<main>'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:680:in `rescue in wait_for_exists': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:name=>"qq", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:675:in `wait_for_exists'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:701:in `wait_for_enabled'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:713:in `wait_for_writable'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:838:in `check_condition'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:802:in `element_call'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/user_editable.rb:10:in `set'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:26:in `block in <main>'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:16:in `exception_check'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:26:in `<main>'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/wait.rb:46:in `until': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:name=>"qq", :tag_name=>"input"}> (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/wait.rb:125:in `wait_until'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:677:in `wait_for_exists'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:701:in `wait_for_enabled'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:713:in `wait_for_writable'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:838:in `check_condition'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:802:in `element_call'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/user_editable.rb:10:in `set'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:26:in `block in <main>'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:16:in `exception_check'
        from /Users/bobjames/Desktop/Automated-Testing-main/send_email.rb:26:in `<main>'
bobjames@Bobs-Air ~ %
```

//..

Comment: When used within a method definition `rescue` definitely works too (`begin` in this case is redundant, while still valid). If it doesn't work for you then there might be some other problem (for example, in your code there is one more essential difference besides `rescue` position - in 1st snippet you call `browser.select...` and in the 2nd it is just `element_to_check` with an unknown content).

Comment: Thanks. The element_to_check is what's passed in as an argument and ends up being the same as browser.select......

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `browser.select_list(:id => "P5500_P_NATIONALITY").select("Americans")` gets evaluated and the result of it sent as the parameter to the `exception_check` function. In other words, the selection is outside the `begin-rescue` block.

You'll need to change the method to support a `block` that can can be evaluated within the `begin-rescue`:

```
def exception_check
    yield
rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError, Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException
    print "Error handling caught an exception: Relationships Page. See log."
    print "\n"
    log_fileWriter("after_header","Relationship Page:",$exception_error_code,"2",test_id)
    screenCapture(browser,"Add Relationship",test_id)
end
```

Then call the method using a `block` instead of a parameter:

```
exception_check { browser.select_list(:id => "P5500_P_NATIONALITY").select("Americans") }
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. Unfortunately it still doesn't seem to be reaching the rescue block. (see above)

Comment: @bobbie_j - Can you show the full exception that you get when running the code? Also can you make a full example that reproduces your problem? Running the above code against say, www.google.ca, works as expected for me.

Comment: Thanks @Justin. Additional info added above

Comment: If you comment out the `log_fileWriter` and `screenCapture` lines, does it then work? For me, I'm only getting an exception because these lines aren't valid (at least not valid in this the minimal example).

Comment: Ahh...yes it works now having commented out those two lines. They work fine in a different context but for some reason I left them in. Problem solved! Thanks for your help.